# Why does `LinearSolve` give this solution for a singular matrix?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I want to solve the matrix system `Ax+b==0`, the equation is as follows (In MATHEMATICA code, I use `AA` and `bb` to represent `A` and `b` in equation.

```
{bb, AA} = {{0., 0.807353 + 0.127872 I, 0., 0.807353 - 0.127872 I, 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., -0.807353 - 0.127872 I, 0., -0.807353 + 0.127872 I, 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., -0.00173224 - 0.026907 I, -0.0382822 - 0.0843441 I, 
  4.76335*10^-18 - 5.75795*10^-17 I, -0.0382822 + 
   0.0843441 I, -0.00173224 + 0.026907 I, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., -1.21339 + 0.0781167 I, -1.90178 + 0.863183 I, 
  0., -1.90178 - 0.863183 I, -1.21339 - 0.0781167 I}, {{0.681598, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, -0.681598, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1.46714, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.46714, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.82559, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.82559, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.21126, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, -1.21126, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, -1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, -1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0.82559, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, -0.82559, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 1.21126, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.21126, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.681598, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.681598, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.46714, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, -1.46714, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {24459.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2.44599*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -52649.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.26499*10^7, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
   14813.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.48136*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -21733.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.17336*10^7, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 14813.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.48136*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -21733.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   2.17336*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
   0, 0, 0, 24459.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2.44599*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -52649.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   5.26499*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0.544007, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.544007, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.83821, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.83821, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0.737568, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.737568, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.35581, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.35581, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 
   0, -1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   1., 0, 0, 0, 0, -1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.737568, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.737568, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.35581, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, -1.35581, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0.544007, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.544007, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.83821, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.83821, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.95223*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, -1.95223*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, -6.59663*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.59663*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.32342*10^7, 0, 0, 0,
    0, -1.32342*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, -2.43273*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.43273*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1.32342*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.32342*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2.43273*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   2.43273*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 1.95223*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.95223*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -6.59663*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   6.59663*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0.527102, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.902105, -0.0381047, 
   1.97961*10^-18, 0.032252, -0.0134366, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.89717, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.11357, 
   0.05251, -1.1669*10^-18, -0.0448925, 0.0203351, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.726018, 0, 0, 
   0, -0.0986374, -0.829503, 2.94472*10^-17, -0.0104496, -0.0199249, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.37738, 0, 0, 0, 
   0.131642, -1.21095, -3.50757*10^-17, 0.0193318, 0.0226718, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, -0.0349483, 
   0.0685689, -1., 0.0685689, -0.0349483, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 
   0.0487879, -0.0819742, -1., -0.0819742, 0.0487879, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.726018, 
   0, -0.0199249, -0.0104496, 1.28285*10^-17, -0.829503, -0.0986374, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.37738, 0, 
   0.0226718, 0.0193318, -1.44857*10^-17, -1.21095, 0.131642, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0.527102, -0.0134366, 0.032252, 
   3.3025*10^-18, -0.0381047, -0.902105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.89717, 
   0.0203351, -0.0448925, -4.28565*10^-18, 0.05251, -1.11357, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.89157*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, -4.80815*10^6, 3.94552*10^6, 5.01417*10^-10, -651517., -421070.,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -6.80819*10^7, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 7.14445*10^6, -6.39465*10^6, -7.75403*10^-10, 1.62243*10^6, 
   272901., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   1.3027*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 3.94552*10^6, -5.17264*10^6, -6.08506*10^-10,
    2.81443*10^6, -651517., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, -2.47143*10^7, 0, 0, 0, -6.39465*10^6, 8.32061*10^6, 
   9.22064*10^-10, -4.91195*10^6, 1.62243*10^6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   7.68341*10^-9, -5.12227*10^-9, 1.23481*10^-10, 2.79397*10^-9, 
   1.10012*10^-8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, -9.77889*10^-9, 
   7.91624*10^-9, -1.23481*10^-10, -3.95812*10^-9, -1.28639*10^-8, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.3027*10^7, 
   0, -651517., 2.81443*10^6, -2.42715*10^-10, -5.17264*10^6, 
   3.94552*10^6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, -2.47143*10^7, 0, 1.62243*10^6, -4.91195*10^6, 1.46968*10^-10, 
   8.32061*10^6, -6.39465*10^6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.89157*10^7, -421070., -651517., 
   4.57265*10^-10, 3.94552*10^6, -4.80815*10^6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -6.80819*10^7, 272901., 
   1.62243*10^6, -4.80592*10^-10, -6.39465*10^6, 7.14445*10^6, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.886273, 
   0.043591, -2.39217*10^-18, -0.0368646, 0.0152343, -0.781879, 
   0.0567719, 1.78127*10^-17, -0.0244502, -0.0138963, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.13544, -0.0635594, 1.26461*10^-18, 
   0.0543889, -0.0248018, -1.30933, -0.0962959, 4.51115*10^-18, 
   0.0442529, 0.0433231}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0.113137, 0.803033, -3.41274*10^-17, 0.0116013, 0.0231257, 
   0.209736, -0.783976, 3.06846*10^-17, -0.00228765, -0.0664327, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.158865, 1.25301, 
   4.19225*10^-17, -0.0239344, -0.026909, -0.354315, -1.30513, \
-1.92218*10^-17, 0.0238072, 0.123574}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0398838, -0.0794265, 1., -0.0794265, 
   0.0398838, -0.0204021, 0.174613, -1., 0.174613, -0.0204021, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0590519, 0.0979871, 1., 
   0.0979871, -0.0590519, -0.014461, -0.222673, -1., -0.222673, \
-0.014461}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0231257, 
   0.0116013, -1.49261*10^-17, 0.803033, 
   0.113137, -0.0664327, -0.00228765, -9.15279*10^-17, -0.783976, 
   0.209736, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, -0.026909, -0.0239344, 1.72177*10^-17, 1.25301, -0.158865, 
   0.123574, 0.0238072, -2.22052*10^-17, -1.30513, -0.354315}, {0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0.0152343, -0.0368646, -3.79996*10^-18, 0.043591, 
   0.886273, -0.0138963, -0.0244502, 1.00555*10^-16, 
   0.0567719, -0.781879, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, -0.0248018, 0.0543889, 5.16276*10^-18, -0.0635594, 1.13544, 
   0.0433231, 0.0442529, -1.71668*10^-17, -0.0962959, -1.30933}, {0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   4.64675*10^6, -3.78095*10^6, -4.82725*10^-10, 592772., 
   424926., -340251., 160852., -5.49545*10^-11, -129052., 204067., 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -7.403*10^6, 
   6.67194*10^6, 8.06008*10^-10, -1.74152*10^6, -247425., 
   431093., -180426., 1.6481*10^-11, 145890., -229877.}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -3.78095*10^6, 4.96241*10^6, 
   5.87177*10^-10, -2.67944*10^6, 592772., 160852., -101539., 
   6.36591*10^-11, 72933.6, -129052., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 6.67194*10^6, -8.67901*10^6, -9.57219*10^-10, 
   5.15799*10^6, -1.74152*10^6, -180426., 
   126839., -3.86899*10^-11, -83747.7, 145890.}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -6.98492*10^-9, 
   4.19095*10^-9, -1.23481*10^-10, -3.20142*10^-9, -1.11759*10^-8, \
-4.83124*10^-9, 2.2701*10^-9, -6.14733*10^-11, -3.95812*10^-9, 
   2.09548*10^-9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   9.77889*10^-9, -6.51926*10^-9, 1.23481*10^-10, 4.19095*10^-9, 
   1.29221*10^-8, 4.88944*10^-9, -2.96859*10^-9, 6.14733*10^-11, 
   6.98492*10^-9, 1.16415*10^-9}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 592772., -2.67944*10^6, 2.48436*10^-10, 
   4.96241*10^6, -3.78095*10^6, -129052., 72933.6, 
   5.17967*10^-11, -101539., 160852., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, -1.74152*10^6, 
   5.15799*10^6, -1.35105*10^-10, -8.67901*10^6, 6.67194*10^6, 
   145890., -83747.7, -8.18553*10^-11, 126839., -180426.}, {0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 424926., 
   592772., -4.54748*10^-10, -3.78095*10^6, 4.64675*10^6, 
   204067., -129052., -3.20825*10^-11, 160852., -340251., 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -247425., -1.74152*10^6, 
   4.81898*10^-10, 6.67194*10^6, -7.403*10^6, -229877., 145890., 
   9.28378*10^-11, -180426., 431093.}, {1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1., 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
   1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0. + 27.725 I, 0. - 4.06836 I, 0. - 3.0604*10^-16 I, 
   0. + 1.71575 I, 0. + 0.558657 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. + 81.0898 I, 0. + 12.2025 I, 
   0. - 4.88115*10^-16 I, 0. - 5.87267 I, 0. - 6.85412 I}, {0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. - 7.52439 I, 
   0. + 13.9334 I, 0. - 1.01465*10^-15 I, 0. - 0.13776 I, 
   0. + 2.30907 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0. + 22.3807 I, 0. + 40.2481 I, 0. + 9.40814*10^-16 I, 
   0. - 2.19887 I, 0. - 8.34859 I}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. - 2.30907 I, 
   0. + 0.13776 I, 0. - 1.73896*10^-15 I, 0. - 13.9334 I, 
   0. + 7.52439 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0. + 8.34859 I, 0. + 2.19887 I, 0. - 1.37134*10^-15 I, 
   0. - 40.2481 I, 0. - 22.3807 I}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. - 0.558657 I, 0. - 1.71575 I, 
   0. + 4.38062*10^-15 I, 0. + 4.06836 I, 0. - 27.725 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. + 6.85412 I, 
   0. + 5.87267 I, 0. - 1.95554*10^-15 I, 0. - 12.2025 I, 
   0. - 81.0898 I}}}
```

Then we can get the solution of this matrix system using `LinearSolve`:

```
solution = LinearSolve[AA, -bb]
```

And as the system is `Ax+b==0`, rahter than `Ax==b`, so we use the following to verify the solution:

```
AA . solution + bb
```

The verification result is as follows:

```
{1.14881*10^-9 - 3.33676*10^-10 I, 2.5436*10^-10 + 6.92565*10^-12 I, 
 3.30403*10^-10 + 2.22421*10^-11 I, -3.86554*10^-9 - 1.53387*10^-10 I,
  6.87567*10^-9 + 5.01157*10^-11 I, 
 3.17232*10^-8 - 1.04774*10^-9 I, -1.07102*10^-8 - 1.16415*10^-9 I, 
 0. + 0. I, 2.32831*10^-10 - 6.98492*10^-10 I, 
 1.15251*10^-8 - 1.62981*10^-9 I, 
 2.56138*10^-9 + 3.71553*10^-10 I, -3.61262*10^-10 - 
  7.63131*10^-12 I, -2.52658*10^-11 + 1.01004*10^-11 I, 
 8.67417*10^-11 - 1.4668*10^-11 I, 
 1.11727*10^-10 - 9.1231*10^-12 I, -2.20025*10^-8 + 3.37604*10^-9 I, 
 1.86265*10^-9 + 1.04774*10^-9 I, 
 0. + 0. I, -3.0268*10^-8 - 5.82077*10^-10 I, -6.40284*10^-9 + 
  5.47152*10^-9 I, -4.9036*10^-11 + 
  5.67851*10^-12 I, -6.2491*10^-11 + 
  7.23503*10^-12 I, -3.41865*10^-12 + 3.9605*10^-13 I, 
 1.15641*10^-11 - 1.33879*10^-12 I, 8.487*10^-12 - 9.82825*10^-13 I, 
 1.18744*10^-8 - 1.16415*10^-10 I, -4.65661*10^-9 + 9.31323*10^-10 I, 
 9.772*10^-11 - 3.39746*10^-10 I, 
 1.86265*10^-8 + 1.5134*10^-9 I, -8.84756*10^-9 - 3.14321*10^-9 I, 
 1.42741*10^-10 - 1.65275*10^-11 I, 2.28806*10^-11 - 2.64924*10^-12 I,
  7.42766*10^-13 - 8.60776*10^-14 I, -3.17769*10^-12 + 
  3.67928*10^-13 I, -8.73713*10^-13 + 
  1.01193*10^-13 I, -6.33008*10^-10 + 
  2.78305*10^-10 I, -2.70666*10^-9 - 2.04636*10^-10 I, 
 5.40339*10^-9 - 2.43754*10^-9 I, 
 5.5843*10^-9 + 3.93811*10^-10 I, -9.26957*10^-9 - 2.40107*10^-10 I, 
 2.78873*10^-11 - 2.35157*10^-12 I, 1.30116*10^-11 - 1.50649*10^-12 I,
  3.25485*10^-15 - 4.42444*10^-16 I, -1.33489*10^-11 + 
  1.5454*10^-12 I, 4.78622*10^-12 - 5.54411*10^-13 I, 
 2.85105*10^-13 + 2.4603*10^-12 I, 1.79856*10^-14 + 1.20015*10^-13 I, 
 0. + 0. I, -3.9968*10^-15 - 9.19265*10^-14 I, -1.64313*10^-14 - 
  1.54932*10^-13 I}
```

As all items are approximate to zero, so it means that the solution is suitable for this matrix system, **but the question is that, as `Det[AA]==0`, it means that `aa` is not full rank and is one singular matrix, so how Mathematica give this specific solution using `LinearSolve`, this equation should have infinite solutions?**

Comment: Apparently, _Mathematica_ just applies `LeastSquares` which finds the, well, least-squares solution: `Max[Abs[LeastSquares[AA, bb] - LinearSolve[AA, bb]]]` returns `0.`.

Comment: I am not happy really happy that no warning is thrown. You would get such a warning if you try an LU-factorization with `LinearSolve[A]`.

Comment: Perhaps I'm totally wrong: Because `MatrixRank[AA]` and `MatrixRank[Join[AA, {bb}]]` are the same `LinearSolve`is able to solve the system!

Comment: Yes, analytically there are infinite solution, but if `LinearSolve` give the least-squares solution(same as `lsqminnorm` in MATLAB?, then which command in Mathematica is the same as  \  **left divide** in MATLAB? @HenrikSchumacher, @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: If you want exact answers use exact numbers. Appending `// Rationalize[#, 0]&` to your definitions will give a verification of all zeroes.

Comment: I wish people would put semicolons at the end of insanely long variable definitions. -- @HenrikSchumacher, from the docs for `LinearSolve`: "For underdetermined systems, LinearSolve will return one of the possible solutions; Solve will return a general solution." Though it would be nice if there were at least a way to turn `On[]` a warning message for this case.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it does not really explain why it doesn't show infinite solutions, but something to observe is that while AA is singular and has no inverse, it does still have a [Moore-Penrose Psuedoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse), which can be used to find the least-squares solution:
`solution = LinearSolve[AA, -bb];`

`ps=PseudoInverse[AA];`

`lsq = ps . (-bb);`

`lsq` and `solution` are very similar, so this may be how the particular solution was calculated:

`Norm[lsq - solution]/Norm[solution]`
(*7.30938*10^-9*)

Comment: @ydd, the default `LinearSolve` use the `lsqminnorm `  in MATLAB which is least-squares solution, and `ps=PseudoInverse[AA]; lsq = ps . (-bb)` also use the least-squares solution, so they get the same solution.   **However, it is maybe just for this case, in other cases, maybe the `ps=PseudoInverse[AA]; lsq = ps . (-bb)`  will not apply the least-squares solution.**

Comment: By the way, the \ in MATLAB is based on the Gauss elimination method, so if you use ` \ ` and use `pinv` or `lsqminnorm`, you will get really different results, **so how to get the solution by Gauss elimination method in Mathematica via `LinearSolve` ?** @MichaelE2

Comment: I don't think the solution by Gauss elimination is unique, but maybe `sol = Array[x, Length@AA] /. First@Solve[AA . Array[x, Length@AA] + bb == 0, Array[x, Length@AA]]`? You can set the free parameters to zero with `sol /. _x ->0` if desired. Or maybe you'd prefer `sol = rr = Chop@RowReduce[Join[AA, List /@ bb, 2]];
Array[x, Length@rr] /. First@Solve[rr . Append[Array[x, Length@rr], 1] == 0, Array[x, Length@rr]]`? -- You can use `NullSpace[AA]` to extend any particular solution to a general solution, if you want all solutions.

Comment: @MichaelE2，It is queer, the command `RowReduce` is Gauss elimination method, right? But you use this method to get the same solution as `LinearSolve`, while in MATLAB, they are 2 different methods and MATLAB give different results, and the command is \ and `lsqminnorm` respectively.

Comment: `RowReduce` gives a (diagonal) *reduced* row echelon form, and solving usually uses a (triangular) row echelon form, probably a minor difference. I'm sure both use LAPACK to get an LU factorization.  The algorithms have variants and scaling factors and so forth that might lead to different results. I have no internal knowledge of what goes on.